# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException only locally

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a question regarding java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.
I build my Maven Projekt in eclipse and everything Looks Fine, however at Runtime i geht the following exception Locally:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I Also found the class at the correct directory in .war file. Then I deployed the Same war file on Tomcat test Server and it Works Fine There. I only See the exception when i Start the Projekt locally and try to Debug it. Does anybody any have an idea how can i get rid of this exception locally as well? What Could be the possible differents between tomcats locally and in the server ?
Regards

P.S I have no access to server data I just can deploy my file on it